# How to get Audio file in UIImagePickerController in ios same as kuTTypeMovie

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new in iOS and i work on pick Audio file like mp3,mp4 etc..

Same as `UIImagePickerControlle`r  and sorce code given below is working fine but it get only video file not audio file i pick only audio file:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When i replace

```
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeAudio, nil];
```

`kUTTypeMovie` with `kUTTypeAudio` application will crash...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can't retrieve audio files using UIImagePicker, you need to use `MPMediaPickerController` [Tutorial](http://midhunmp-iostips.blogspot.in/2013/05/showing-songs-list-in-ios-using.html)

Comment: hello if there are to posible to select audio file select same as UIImagePickerController

Comment: Hello sir,How to get list of audio file from gallery in ios . when download song from whatsapp application that is store in gallery in iPhone how to get that list of song in UIImagePickerView or any other option to view  it..

Comment: You can pick audios using `MPMediaPickerController`, there is no way to get audio using `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't fetch `Audio` files by using `UIImagePickerControlle`r,Instead you should use `MPMediaPickerController`

```
MPMediaPickerController *pickerController = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
pickerController.prompt = @"Select Song";
pickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After picking you get a call back in MpMediaPicker delegate method:

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    MPMediaItem *theChosenSong = [[mediaItemCollection items]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *songTitle = [theChosenSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSURL *assetURL = [theChosenSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset  *songAsset  = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
}
```

Comment: i also want to know that how to convert that selected audio to NSData @user3879130

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible to add or fetch mp3 files from library.  You can only get image and videos from photo library . `kUTTypeMovie`  is an abstract type identifier for a media format which contain both video and audio. `kUTTypeAudio` is not supported.